# "internationalisation of mail in jhipster"

Tags: jhipster

"I'm using jhipster for my application, I've tried adding email internationalisation to the messages_en.properties and message.properties and message_en.properties files under the i18n folder. then in the html file under templates / mail / activationEmail.html, I did as below but it does not work by changing the language"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="#{email.activation.title}">JHipster activation</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/favicon.ico|}" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="#{email.activation.greeting(${user.login})}">
        Dear
    </p>
    <p th:text="#{email.activation.text1}">
        Your JHipster account has been created, please click on the URL below to activate it:
    </p>
    <p>
        <a th:with="url=(@{|${baseUrl}/#/activate?key=${user.activationKey}|})" th:href="${url}"
        th:text="${url}">Activation link</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span th:text="#{email.activation.text2}">Regards, </span>
        <br/>
        <em th:text="#{email.signature}">Jhipster.</em>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you generate an application with JHipster you can choose the languages you want your application to have. To modify the text of the registration email you only have to edit the template in the file messages_languageYouWantToEdit.properties, as you have done.

You may have to compile the application again to be able to view your changes correctly.

> If you are using Maven
>
> ./mvnw (on Mac OS X/Linux) // mvnw (on Windows):
>
> Or Gradle
>
> ./gradlew (on Mac OS X/Linux) // gradlew (on Windows)

You have more information about the internationalization of Jhipster on its website:
https://www.jhipster.tech/installing-new-languages/

Comment: locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("fr");
   context = new Context(locale);
   context.setVariable(INVENTION_FILE, inventionFile);
   context.setVariable(BASE_URL, jHipsterProperties.getMail().getBaseUrl());                                                                                         Problem is here how to set the local language come from front

Comment: If you have not changed anything on the front, a menu should appear at the top, in the navbar, where you can select the language.